# usb2: How to declare interfaces and endpoints for implicit feedback

Tags: audio, usb, endpoint, feedback

I am carrying on a project, which simplifying a lot, I could classify as a USB sound card.

Since my device uses its own clock for audio I have declared the following interfaces/endpoints:

- **Interface 1** containing 2 endpoint:

  - **EP 1 OUT**: Isochronous, Async, Data
  - **EP 1 IN**: Isochronous, No sync, explicit feedback
- **Interface 2** containing 1 endpoint:

  - **EP 2 IN**: Isochronous, Async, Data

This way it works quite well in Linux, the host "chases" the clock of my device even when I force it to vary (just to evaluate the goodness of my feedback implementation)

However, in the USB2 specification I read about implicit feedback:

[image]

I wanted to try this mode as well, declaring **EP 2 IN** as *implicit feedback* instead of *Data*, either by leaving the implicit feedback EP in as well or removing it, however in neither scenario does it work. The device is correctly enumerated, but when I select it in some SW (such as Ardour), ALSA, almost immediately, reports a generic "*I/O Error*"

Perhaps **EP 1 OUT** and **EP 2 IN** are not properly grouped, as is required by the specification. To group them, do I have to put them both in one interface? In this way, though, it will no longer be possible to open one of the two streams only?

regards